# Unable to get value of DropDownListFor in controller on submit from view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using a `@Html.DropDownListFor<>` in my page that is bound to my ViewModel but when I submit the page to the controller for processing I get the error "The Type filed is required." which is an error thrown since the proptery of my VM "Type" has the Data Annotation `[Required]`. I think is this due to the fact the `@Html.DropDownList<>` generates HTML code with `name=Type` while all the other HTML generated has `name=Section.XXXX` where XXX is the property name. I have been trying to figure out how to make the `@Html.DropDownList<>` generate the `name=Section.Type` property, assuming my theory is correct. So my question is really, is my theory correct and if so how to get it to generate the correct html and if not what might be wrong?

Section EF Mode:

```
public class Section
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int16 ID { get; set; }

    public Int64? LogoFileID { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(250), Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string RouteName { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(15), Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Synopsis { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LogoFileID")]
    public virtual File Logo { get; set; }
}
```

Section View Model:

```
public class SectionAddEditVM
{
    public Section Section { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Type { get; set; }
    public string SelectedType { get; set; }

    public SectionAddEditVM()
    {
        Section = new Section();
        Type = new List<SelectListItem>();
        Type.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Books", Text = "Books" });
        Type.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Cinema", Text = "Cinema" });
        Type.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Collection", Text = "Collection" });
        Type.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Game", Text = "Game" });
    }
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

    <p>
        <label for="Title">Seciton Title:</label> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Section.Title)
        <br />
        <label for="RouteName">Section Route:</label> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Section.RouteName)
        <br />
        <label for="Type">Section Type:</label> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Type, new SelectList(Model.Type, "Text", "Value"))
        <br />
        <label for="LogoFile">Logo Image:</label> <input id="LogoFile" name="LogoFile" type="file" />
        <br />
        <label for="Synopsis">Synopsis:</label> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Section.Synopsis)
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Add new section" />
    </p>
}
```

Controller:

```
    [Route("Add"), HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddSection(SectionAddEditVM NewSection, HttpPostedFileBase LogoFile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                if (LogoFile != null && LogoFile.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    if (LogoFile.ContentType == "image/png")
                    {
                        string FileName = NewSection.Section.RouteName + "Logo";
                        NewSection.Section.LogoFileID = FileUploadHelper.UploadSiteImage("Logos", FileName, LogoFile);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("File Type", "Logo Files must be PNG files.");
                        return View(NewSection);
                    }
                }

                using (db)
                {
                    db.Sections.Add(NewSection.Section);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                //SiteUpdateHelper.RecordChange("New", "New Section", NewSection.Title, "Eagle_f90");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                ModelState.AddModelError("Processing Error", "There was a problem processing the new section, please try again later.");
                return View(NewSection);
            }
        }
        return View(NewSection);
    }
```

Generated HTML:

```
<select id="Type" name="Type"><option value="Books">Books</option>
<option value="Cinema">Cinema</option>
<option value="Collection">Collection</option>
<option value="Game">Game</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're mapping the dropdown to the wrong member:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Section.Type, new SelectList(Model.Type, "Value", "Text"))
```

`Model.Type` is your data source (i.e. `List<SelectListItem>`), but you're wanting to bind the selected value to `Model.Section.Type`, not `Model.Type`.

Also, Khaled is right, you do have the value / text parameters the wrong way around, so I swapped them above.  The reason that doesn't appear to be a problem for you at the moment, is because your text and values are the same.  As soon as you have any that differ, that would give you an issue.

Comment: SelectedType has no value for the add page, it is simply to hold what Type was selected for the edit page. It has no use in the add page that I am having a problem with.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete Your setup is a little odd, but you can try `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Section.Type, ...)`.

Comment: changing it to `m.Section.Type` worked. If you want to update your answer I will mark it as so. Also, what about my setup is odd? it was generated from questions asked and answered from SO.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete Glad it worked for you.  I'll update now. Ignore my other comment.  I misread something in your code, that's all.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've accidentally misplaced the value and text names:
the second parameter should be the value and the third is the text:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Type, new SelectList(Model.Type, "Value", "Text"))
```

Edit:
try

@Htm`l.DropDownListFor(m => m.Section.SelectedType, new SelectList(Model.Type, "Value", "Text`"))

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. I have added the HTML generated and, as you can see, the Value and Text are the same which is what I want it to do.

Comment: I actually don't know if this'd help, but try this: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Section.SelectedType , new SelectList(Model.Type, "Text", "Value"))

Comment: Section does not have a declaration of SelectedType, that is only in the ViewModel. Also that is only to pull what Type was stored in the DB to set it as selected in the drop down for the edit page.